# Could not find gem 'xcode-install' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or in gems cached in vendor/cache

Tags: ruby

when I use this command to run fastlane:

```
bundle exec fastlane beta
```

shows error:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios on  main! ⌚ 14:59:47
$ bundle exec fastlane beta                                                                                                      ‹ruby-3.0.0›
Could not find gem 'xcode-install' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or in gems cached in vendor/cache.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
(base)
```

then I install `xcode-install` like this:

```
 $ gem install xcode-install                                                                                                      ‹ruby-3.0.0›
Fetching xcode-install-2.6.8.gem
Successfully installed xcode-install-2.6.8
Parsing documentation for xcode-install-2.6.8
Installing ri documentation for xcode-install-2.6.8
Done installing documentation for xcode-install after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
(base)
```

still not fix this problem. what should I do to fix it?

Comment: have you tried `bundle install`?

Comment: yes, I have already tried bundle install command. @Geoffroy

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile you need to add this line:

```
gem "xcode-install"
```

Right after

```
gem "fastlane"
```

And run fastlane command again.